# Haskell: Calling a function of two variables on N variable

Tags: haskell

What is the best way to call a function of two variables on more than two variables?

For example given the function `max`

```
Prelude> :t max
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

if I want the maximum of the variables `x,y,z` I can call

```
max (max x y) z
```

but it is verbose for large numbers of elements.

One way would be to do it recursively on a list (using the an example from "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good"

```
maximum :: Ord x => [x] -> x; 
maximum [] = error "maximum of empty list" 
maximum (x:[]) = x
maximum (x:xs) = max x (maximum(xs))
```

So using this I would have to create an array and then a function like this to operate on arrays. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In this case, there is already a [`maximum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:maximum) function in the Prelude. [Here is how it is implemented](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#maximum) (and note that it is specialised for `Int`s and `Integer`s).

Comment: Note that `[x]` is not an *array*, it is a *list*, particularly, an immutable singly-linked list. You can find implementations of arrays at `Data.Array` and `Data.Vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you are talking about are not a "function which operate on an array", just a common recursive pattern.

Of course there are function to deal with recursive pattern, as fold for example.
Your maximum function could then be redefined as,

```
maximum xs = foldl' max 0 xs -- assuming all the value are upper than 0.
```

if the restriction on the value of the list bother you can use a variant of foldl', foldl1' which will replace the seed (0 upper) by, the first element of list.

```
maximum xs = foldl1' max xs
```

Almost every recursive structure is foldable (List, Tree, Graph...).
But their are other recursive pattern, which can be exploited using map or filter.

Anyway a good introduction on recursion using fold,
[A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf)

Comment: You should consider using `foldl1'` in this case to avoid space leaks

Comment: You're right, I intentionally focus my answer to deal about recursion, then space optimization, strictness ... have been put on the side. I guess it better to proceed step by step and not to confuse people with extract information which treat issue out of the scope of the initial question.

Comment: I'm not sure. IMHO it's reasonably good advice to *always* use `foldl'` and *almost never* `foldl`, so why not tell the beginners exactly this, without even mentioning space issues etc.?

Comment: I agree, `foldl` is pretty much just evil. If you want to keep it simple, explain `foldr` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to zurgl's answer, Haskell has a type class [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) for containers. There is an utility method

```
maximum :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> a
```

defined simply as

```
maximum = foldr1 max
```

So for whatever container type that implements `Foldable` (denoted by `t`) and whatever element type with ordering (`a`) this single function can be used. In other words, if a data type implements folding operation over its elements, any aggregating function over it can be defined in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to call a function of two variables on more than two variables?

Well let's see here. In Racket, I would say use a macro.

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax apply*
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(apply* f x y)
     (f x y)]
    [(apply* f x y rest ...)
     (apply* f (f x y) rest ...)]))

(define (plus a b) (+ a b))
(apply* plus 1 2 3 4 5) ;; => 15
```

Here we have deemed that the `apply*` form takes a function of two arguments, and calls it on an arbitrarily long list of arguments. This will literally expand `(apply* max x y z)` into `(max (max x y) z)`, allowing you to write the pretty code and letting the macro expander turn it into the verbose code.

---

However, Haskell macros are annoying to deal with, and rather unidiomatic. So let's use a function instead. What will this function look like?

```
applyStar :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

The first argument is a 2-arg function, which takes two things of the same type, and spits out a thing of that type. This we can see from the desired result: `max (max x y) z`, the output must be the same type as the inputs. Haskell doesn't let you define functions of variable arity, so in order to simulate that, we write a function that takes a *list* of arguments, `[a]`.

Stop. Hoogle time! If you search for the type signature `(a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a` at http://haskell.org/hoogle , then you'll find that this is called `foldl1` and is already implemented for you.